# Couldnt understand variable scope in JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, bluebird

Here is my following code block. I am passing my `val` object from function `test1` to `test2` and modify its value in `test2` and send it back.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var list = [1,2,3];

var test1 = function(test) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        var val = {"name" : "my_name","age" : 25};
        for (var item in list) {
            (function (item) {
                console.log("val",val);
                test2(val)
                    .then(function(test2Response) {
                        console.log("test2Response",test2Response)
                    });
            })(item)
        }
    });
};


var test2 = function(val1) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        console.log("val1",val1)
        val1.name = val1.name + "_1"
        resolve(val1)
    })
}


test1()
```

And here is my value of my variables `val`and `val1` at various stages.

```
val { name: 'my_name', age: 25 }
val1 { name: 'my_name', age: 25 }


val { name: 'my_name_1', age: 25 }
val1 { name: 'my_name_1', age: 25 }


val { name: 'my_name_1_1', age: 25 }
val1 { name: 'my_name_1_1', age: 25 }


test2Response { name: 'my_name_1_1_1', age: 25 }
test2Response { name: 'my_name_1_1_1', age: 25 }
test2Response { name: 'my_name_1_1_1', age: 25 }
```

I couldnt understand why the value of val changes for every iteration even though I update only `val1` not `val`. How can I maintain the `val` intact and modify only 'val1`?

Comment: javascript objects are passed by reference. try [underscore: `dupe = _.clone(obj)`](http://underscorejs.org/#clone)

Comment: My bad I didnt know it....Works like a charm !!!!! Thanks man

Comment: Your `new Promise` in `test1` doesn't work at all. You should use `Promise.all`

Answer (score 0):

When you pass val to `test2` as `val1` it is still the same reference in memory. You would need to clone the value before passing to `test2` which can easily be done by doing like this before calling `test2`:

```
var copyOfVal = Object.assign({}, val) // this just creates a new object using the same contents of val but different references in memory.
```

then pass `copyOfVal` into `test2` and you will get separate results.

Comment: woa! btw this is ES6

Comment: PS [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34283281/1380669) mentions that this approach does not "deep clone", although i don't know exactly what that means :)

Comment: `_.clone` is also only shallow clone, all that means is if you have an object with nested objects, the nested objects wont be cloned and actually have the same reference as the initial object. Meaning if you change one of the nested properties it will change on both the original and the copy. Lodash does have a `_.cloneDeep(obj)` that does recursively clone if you an object that fits that pattern.